# JRE not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, java-11, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to install java 11 on ubuntu 20.04 vps using this tutorial [how to install java on ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04-id)

But after installation and done setting `$JAVA_HOME` variable, I can't run a library because `libjvm.so` was not found.

Turns out `jre` not exist on `$JAVA_HOME` for all java version I installed (openjdk, oracle java). Why that happen and how to make jre installed?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is the JDK location. It would of course not be set for a JRE installation.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't run a library"? We don't run libraries.

Comment: And what is the output when you type `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code

$ sudo dpkg --purge "package-name"

Example

$ sudo dpkg --purge jdk-15.0.1

Then install JDK

And at last run the command

$ apt install -f